# Broker configuration in Confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I want to increase the size of default message size (1MB) and I know for that I have to set message.max.bytes and one more property on Broker side and restart the cluster. However, I cant find any such place on the Confluent Cloud to do that. Can some please guide how can I make this change in the cluster. Thanks.

Comment: I think Confluent Cloud has its own limit. I believe it's 5MB